# Why is my animation appearing jittery

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

I made an animation using the cycles renderer but the end animation is jittery, and I don't know why. I've attached the final video file link here. I'm using the latest 2.92 version of blender[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jTt183XlgTkSGoCYbFQg3tjHw-BkYfWh/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by ‘jittery’. Watching on phone screen I can see some jumping in the shadows under the table due to denoiser. Is that what you’re referring to?

Comment: No two frames produce the same picture every one of the frames has a slightly varied image that makes it look like every picture was taken a different lighting condition

Comment: I've just reviewed it on a larger screen and the only thing I can see is denoiser "noise". Try disabling the denoiser and see if that makes for less jitter. You may need to increase the number of samples to improve the image quality to reduce the variation.

Comment: How many samples would you recommend? This one is at 75.

Comment: 75 samples is a very low number of samples for such a complicated scene. The render engine will really struggle to deal with the shadowy areas effectively, leaving a lot of boise - which is why those parts are showing the problem. It would be OK for still images but animated brings out the discrepancies. Samples are a matter of diminishing returns - more will almost always be better but the higher you get the less improvement you’ll see. Try with double and see how that improves matters.